# Ignore a string in R

Tags: r, string

At the start of my code i assign the following values

```
Hierarchy_1 <- "Store_2"
Hierarchy_2 <- "Store"
Hierarchy_3 <- "SKK"
```

And then i assign them in the following vector, which is my stable columns of my csv. However in order to be a dynamic code there must be a case where Hierarchy_1 will not exist as a column. Is there a function to ignore Hierarchy_1 to avoid deleting it from StableCols vector and later stages of my code?

```
StableCols<- c(Hierarchy_1,Hierarchy_2,Hierarchy_3,DateName,DepVarName)
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. How do you use this `StableCols`? What isn't working? Where is the example data and desired output? We can't read minds. If you just using this vector in order to subset columns from a data frame, you can use `intersect` in order to make sure all the column names are valid. Here is a **reproducible example**: `mtcars[intersect(names(mtcars), c("mpg", "wt", "test"))]`

Comment: I am asking if there is a function which will ignore the string Hierarchy_1 from my vector StableCols. For example if i can do ignore(Hierarchy_1) and if i run StableCols the output will be Hierarchy_2 Hierarchy_3 DateName DepVarName although i have Hierarchy_1 in the StableCols

Comment: Still unclear... Maybe `setdiff(StableCols, Hierarchy_1)`?

Comment: If your are thinking about not reading the columns with `read.table` the parameter `colClasses` allows for a NULL value in those columns which should not be read...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `get0` function.

`get0` search for an object in R enviroment, return NULL if not found.

```
Hierarchy_1 <- "Store_2"
Hierarchy_2 <- "Store"
Hierarchy_3 <- "SKK"

StableCols<- c(get0("Hierarchy_1"), Hierarchy_2, Hierarchy_3)
StableCols
# [1] "Store_2" "Store"   "SKK" 

rm(Hierarchy_1)
StableCols<- c(get0("Hierarchy_1"), Hierarchy_2, Hierarchy_3)
StableCols
# [1] "Store" "SKK"
```

You can also use the `dynGet` function.

```
StableCols<- c(dynGet("Hierarchy_1", ifnotfound = NULL), Hierarchy_2, Hierarchy_3)
```

**To David:**

You are right about `dynGet`. I have no idea. Maybe the following info can help.

**From `?get`:**

dynGet() is somewhat experimental and to be used inside another function. It looks for an object in the callers, i.e., the sys.frame()s of the function. Use with caution.

I tested another function `mget`. It also works.

```
StableCols<- c(unname(unlist(mget("Hierarchy_1", ifnotfound = list(NULL)))), 
               Hierarchy_2, Hierarchy_3)
```

Comment: No problem. Can you please accept my answer as the right one by checking the tick on the left? Thx!

Comment: `c(dynGet("Hierarchy_1", ifnotfound = NULL), Hierarchy_2, Hierarchy_3)` doesn't work if `Hierarchy_1` *is* present. As in `Hierarchy_1 <- "Store_2" ; dynGet("Hierarchy_1", ifnotfound = NULL)` returns `NULL`. This is an experimental function that seem to work only *within* another function

Answer (score 0):

You can use rm

```
c(rm(Hierarchy_1), Hierarchy_2, Hierarchy_3, DateName, DepVarName)
```

or you can use subset

```
c(subset(StableCols, StableCols!=Hierarchy_1))
```

Or

```
StableCols[-1]
```

will remove element at first index and print rest